# How to add NUnit in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, nunit

I need to write test cases for my application. I've chosen NUnit. Please let me know how to add NUnit to my Visual Studio IDE. where can I download them?

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247900/is-there-a-free-visual-studio-addin-for-nunit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question is a bit ambiguous..

- Are you interested in learning nunit (In which case nunit.org would be the place to look along with some books on TDD/UnitTesting)
- If you're trying to integrate nunit with VisualStudio IDE, I'd go with the external executable approach listed as Option#1 [here](http://www.dev102.com/2008/03/22/3-ways-to-run-nunit-from-visual-studio/) or TestDriven.net Option#2

Answer (score 6):

Best place to start would probably be: http://testdriven.net/

They have NUnit, and a host of other unit testing suites that can integrate with various versions of Visual Studio, as well as some documentation on them.