# NUnit not working on Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nunit

I'm new to NUnit and I just download it today and I can't get it working with visual studio. (I'm new to Visual Studio as well)
I'm following TekPub's Mastering C# 4.0 tutorial.

Screenshot: Something is missing within the red circle area. There should be some "green thing" on the side that let you double click on it and run the NUnit test.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20422001/NunitMissing.jpg

As you can see on the above screenshot, the NUnit seems not working....

Did I miss something? Please advice. Thanks

*EDIT*
This is how it SHOULD look like. I took a screenshot from the video tutorial:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20422001/nunit.jpg

and here is the project files:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20422001/MasteringCSharp.rar

As you can see, I don't have "Unit Test" Tab and "Unit Test Session"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't doing anything wrong.  Out of the box, NUnit doesn't integrate directly with Visual Studio. The screenshot from the video appears to be using Resharper's test runner.

Typically testing with NUnit requires you to compile your test project and then load it into the NUnit GUI (nunit.exe) where the tests can be run from there. When using the NUnit GUI, the project will reload anytime the assembly is recompiled.  (I sometimes prefer having this in a separate process as it doesn't tie up Visual Studio's UI, but that's a matter of preference.)

The added advantage of using a third party test runner like Resharper, TestDriven.net, Galileo, etc is that it allows you to run or debug the tests directly from within the IDE.  You can accomplish the same thing using NUnit by configuring Visual Studio to attach to NUnit and debug your tests from the external process.  This [post shows you how](https://stackoverflow.com/q/759854/30809).

Answer (score 3):

I haven't seen that particular video, but it sounds like you need an NUnit test runner for Visual Studio.

Check out the following:

[Visual NUnit 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c8164c71-0836-4471-80ce-633383031099) - free!

[TestDriven.net](http://www.testdriven.net/default.aspx)

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/unit_testing.html)

Answer (score 0):

That my friend is **JetBrains' Resharper** - it's a paid add-in to Visual Studio that allows you to run tests from within the IDE. Highly recommended if you're working for a prolonged period in VS.

Of course since you're just starting out, you could use the NUnit GUI to run your tests. You can also set it to run tests after each build. 
`Tools > Settings > Test Loader > Assembly Reload. Check "Re-Run last tests run". Apply changes`