# specify NUnit test to run

Tags: c#, nunit

I have an NUnit project creating a Console Application for running tests.  The entry point looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] my_args = { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location };

        int returnCode = NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(my_args);

        if (returnCode != 0)
            Console.Beep();

    }
}
```

What can I pass in as an argument if I wanted to run this one test ONLY:

```
[TestFixture]
public class EmailNotificationTest
{
    [Test]
    public void MailerDefaultTest()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(false);
    }
}
```

Clearly this is supported, and just as clearly I have no idea how to do it.

**UPDATE**

It looks like with v3+, this is possible with the `--test` option, per [the documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line).

Comment: I haven't used the ConsoleRunner, but it probably honors the `[Explicit]` and `[Category]` attributes.

Comment: For those looking for `nunit3-console.exe` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37297838/run-individual-test-from-nunit3-console-exe

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can mark your test with `[Category("RunOnlyThis")]` attribute, and then tell NUnit to run tests only matching this specific category:

```
 /include:RunOnlyThis
```

is the attribute you need to add to console runner arguments. More [here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.4).

Comment: This isn't necessary from the GUI, though... I would expect to be able to be specific without making code changes so that I could localize a specific test like I can do from the GUI.  Is this not possible?

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: NUnit doc remains silent about that, I'd suppose console runner doesn't allow it then. Having that in mind, I'd go with attaching debugger - it's pretty easy and you can find how to do that on SO ([for example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759854/how-do-i-run-nunit-in-debug-mode-from-visual-studio)).

Comment: I ended up using a `/fixture:EmailNotificationTest` and put my test in its own class.  Attaching the debugger each time I tweak something is annoying... but the answer does seem to be "you can't do it".  Lame.

Comment: How to run a category from cmd using dotnet test?

Comment: Comment for future visitors: This parameter does not work in newer versions. Nunit3 changed the parameters for console runner.

Answer (score 21):

The latest version (NUnit 3) allows to debug tests and also to specify test(s) for execution.

**Debug**

The `--debug` option launches debugger to debug tests, for example:

```
nunit3-console.exe "C:\path\to\the\tests.dll" --debug
```

**Filter tests**

Now you have a number of different ways to select test(s) to run. The first option is `--test=NAMES`. Combining this option and `--debug` you can easily debug only one test, for example:

```
nunit3-console.exe "C:\path\to\the\tests.dll" --debug --test="EmailNotificationTest.MailerDeSecondTest"
```

Don't forget about the namespace if the class has it.

Using `--testlist=PATH` option you can run all tests specified in a file, for example:

```
nunit3-console.exe "C:\path\to\the\tests.dll" --debug --testlist="testnames.txt"
```

There is also `--where=EXPRESSION` option indicating what tests                             will be run. This option is intended to extend or replace the earlier `--test`, `--include` and `--exclude` options. Please check the [official documentation](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=3.0) if you want to know more about this option.

Comment: The official doc sadly hasn't specified what `NAMES` really is. Looks like it's the fully qualified classname ?

Comment: for the --testlist, how do you specify a testlist found in the DLL? i keep getting unable to locate file error. Where do we store these test files?

Comment: @gideon - using nunit3 in C#, the pattern that works for me is: --test="namespace.class-name.method-name". Also, the --debug switch isn't necessary for this

Answer (score 5):

You can use **/run** switch of NUnit console to specify the test that you want to run.

Like this:

```
/run:namespace.classname.functionName
```

E.g.

```
nunit-console.exe "C:\UnitTests.dll" /run:UnitTests.EmailNotificationTest.MailerDefaultTest
```

Answer (score 4):

As @Toto said, use the [NUnit Gui](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunit-gui&r=2.6), you can pick and choose.

[image]

Comment: Yes this is how I know it is possible, but that is not what I am trying to do.  In this case, my latest code changes broke some unit tests, and I am trying to find root cause.  If I run the NUnit project as a console app from visual studio, I can put breakpoints in and trace the code, which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: You can attach visual studio to nunit, your breakpioints will be reach. I do it often.
There is also http://www.testdriven.net/ wich provides rightclick functionality in visual studio to launch unit test with visual studio debugger (really useful).

Answer (score 2):

An application comes with NUnit, and the application can launch the test you want. It's really useful, and you don't have to write code to run test.

Comment: I really want to automatically attach it to the debugger, which the application does not allow me to do (or at least, not easily).  I have a few tests that are failing and I'm trying to see why.

Answer (score 0):

When using NUnit, you can run the tests using NUnit Console like this:

```
NUNIT3-CONSOLE.exe [inputfiles] [options]
```

To run the specific tests, you can use `--test=FULLNAMES` option or `--testlist=FILE` option.

`--test=FULLNAMES`: Comma-separated list of FULLNAMES of tests to run or explore. This option may be repeated. Note that this option is retained for backward compatibility. The --where option can now be used instead.
`--testlist=FILE`: The name (or path) of a FILE containing a list of tests to run or explore, one per line. May also include comment lines, indicated by `#` in the first column.

More info can be found in the [NUnit docs website](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Console-Command-Line.html)