# Run Individual Test from Nunit3-console.exe

Tags: c#, selenium, visual-studio-2015, nunit

when i run

```
nunit3-console.exe (myfilepath)\dll file
```

The Console Runner Runs all my tests.

what command do i need to run in order to run individual tests? i tried

```
nunit3-console.exe  /run:namespace.class.method (myfilepath)\dll file
```

it says that I am using an invalid argument. can someone provide me with the correct syntax?

THanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want to look at the [--where command line option](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line) to run individual tests or filter your tests. It is new for NUnit 3. The `--where` option uses the [test selection language](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Selection-Language) which is a little bit like SQL for tests.

```
nunit-console --where "method =~ /Source.*Test/ && class =~ 'My.Namespace.Classname'" test.dll
```

For simple filters, you can also use the `--test=NAMES` option with a simple list of test names separated by commas.

```
nunit3-console.exe --test=namespace.class.method test.dll
```

With `TestCase` and other data driven tests, the test name for individual tests can be difficult to determine. If that is the case, you can use the `--explore` option.