# nunit assertexception when debugging

Tags: c#, nunit, testdriven.net

This is a simple question, I came across a scenario which got me thinking about the way I have been debugging NUnit tests.

I have a class similar to this

```
public class SomeClass {
   public static bool SomeMethod(){
      return true;
   }
}
```

Now I have a NUnit test like so

```
[TestFixture]
public class UnitTests
{
   [Test]
   public void TestOne()
   {
      var retval = SomeClass.SomeMethod();
      Assert.IsFalse(retval, "Test Failed"); 
   }
}
```

When I run the test in Debug I get this exception

[image: AssertException]

Part of me is saying this is how it should be, in that NUnit would normally catch this exception as the failure, whereas the other part of me is saying no there should not be an exception here the test should just fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Assert.IsFalse` is expecting False.
You can use `Assert.IsTrue` or `Assert.AreEqual(true, retval)`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.isfalse%28v=vs.80%29).

> Assert.IsFalse Method - Verifies that a specified condition is false.

Comment: this is a test case to catch the exception I am getting, this case is the simplest way I could demonstrate the exception

Comment: Hmm.. If you get a exception it will mark the test as failed. This is how Assert works, or am i missunderstanding you at the moment?

Comment: Oh ok. Well when using the Assert.IFalse(true), this will generate a exception, this will not let you continue. This is by design, if the exception is thrown the test will be marked as failed. It's the same for MSTest and all the test-frameworks that i know about. But i can't quite understand your question. Do you want a Assert.ExceptionIsThrown() or something simular? Or only a explanation about why in the debugger you see the error?

Comment: [Here](http://nunit.com/index.php?p=conditionAsserts&r=2.6.1) is the link to the _NUnit_ documentation on `Assert.IsFalse` etc. When an `Assert` is not fulfilled, NUnit always throws `AssertionException`. Then it should be up to your test runner to handle this exception or not.

Comment: thanks jonas I just couldn't find why the exception was being thrown as I said in the question I suspected that it was the way it was meant to work but had doubts. Thanks for your answer you have solved my problem

Comment: No problem, glad i could help you figureing this out, thought you ment something else from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this Nunit tests inside VS? Try compile and run your tests through Nunit test runner, outside VS.

If you want run inside VS, try some plugins like Resharper, TestDriven.NET.

Take a look at here too:
[How do I run NUnit in debug mode from Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759854/how-do-i-run-nunit-in-debug-mode-from-visual-studio)

Comment: I am running inside VS 2010 I have Resharper, looking at your link now thanks

Comment: link was very good upscore unfortunately does not solve my problem