# Debug Visual Studio 2013 Using C# with Selenium WebDriver and NUnit

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2013, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I've been writing some code and, fortunately, it's been working fine up until yesterday when I added some new functionality that does not work correctly.  Hence, I want to debug it to figure out how to fix it.  When I put a breakpoint in my code and press F5 to start debugging I get the following message in my console and it does nothing.

```
'Selenium.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Selenium.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Selenium.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Selenium.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Selenium.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Selenium.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Selenium.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Selenium.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Selenium.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Selenium.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Selenium.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Selenium.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.Sync.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Selenium.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Selenium.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime\12.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Selenium.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Selenium.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\DropBox\Automation\Eclipse\Workspace\C\Selenium_EXTMethod\Selenium_ExtMethod\bin\Debug\Selenium.vshost.exe'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Selenium.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Selenium.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Selenium.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Selenium.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Selenium.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Selenium.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Selenium.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Selenium.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.CSharp\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.CSharp.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Selenium.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Selenium.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'Selenium.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Selenium.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x1784 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x28d8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'Selenium.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: Selenium.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\DropBox\Automation\Eclipse\Workspace\C\Selenium_EXTMethod\Selenium_ExtMethod\bin\Debug\Selenium.exe'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x2244 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x3298 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[4956] Selenium.vshost.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Are you using one of methods suggested in below post to run tests in debugging mode ? 

[link(]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/759854/how-do-i-run-nunit-in-debug-mode-from-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

It must have been one of those days as I realized that I had simply tried to debug a method rather than the test itself.  Now it is debugging.  Just needed to debug correctly is all.  ;)